# Uncomfortable output of mode() in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with several columns (the features).

```
>>> print(df)

   col1  col2
a     1     1
b     2     2
c     3     3
d     3     2
```

I would like to compute the mode of one of them. This is what happens:

```
>>> print(df['col1'].mode())

0    3
dtype: int64
```

I would like to output simply the value `3`.
This behavoiur is quite strange, if you consider that the following very similar code is working:

```
>>> print(df['col1'].mean())

2.25
```

So two questions: why does this happen? How can I obtain the pure mode value as it happens for the mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because [Series.mode()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mode.html) can return multiple values:

consider the following DF:

```
In [77]: df
Out[77]:
   col1  col2
a     1     1
b     2     2
c     3     3
d     3     2
e     2     3

In [78]: df['col1'].mode()
Out[78]:
0    2
1    3
dtype: int64
```

From docstring:

> Empty if nothing occurs at least 2 times.  **Always returns Series
>   even if only one value.**

If you want to chose the first value:

```
In [83]: df['col1'].mode().iloc[0]
Out[83]: 2

In [84]: df['col1'].mode()[0]
Out[84]: 2
```

Comment: Hi max and thanks for your help. What about my second question?

Answer (score 2):

I agree that it's too cumbersome

df['col1'].mode().iloc[0].values[0]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

a series can have one mean(), but a series can have more than one mode()

like

<2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,6,7,8> its mode  2,3,4.

the output must be indexed

Answer (score 1):

`mode()` will return all values that tie for the most frequent value.

In order to support that functionality, it must return a collection, which takes the form of a `dataFrame` or Series.

For example, if you had a series:

`[2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 6]`

Then the most frequent values occur twice. The result would then be the series `[2, 3, 5]` since each of these occur twice.

If you want to collapse this into a single value, you can access the first value, compute the `max()`, `min()`, or whatever makes most sense for your application.