# Return only mode value from DataFrame

Tags: python

I am trying to return the value for mean, mode and median for a column of data from a DataFrame using mean(), mode() and median() and then print these out. All works fine for mean and median but for mode I get

```
mode = 0   121
               dtype: float64
```

From investigating it appears that mode() returns a table:

|  | data |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 121.75 |

with the data type following it and I imagine that is why I am not just getting the value of mode. How can I get this to work so that only the mode value is returned?

```
Code used is:
def mean_mode_median(df):
    mean = df['frequency'].mean()
    mode = df['frequency'].mode()
    median = df['frequency'].median()
    print(f'The mean, mode and median frequencies (in MHz) are: \nmean = {mean:2f} MHz, \nmode = {mode} MHz \nmedian = {median} MHz.')
```

Comment: Can you [edit] and share the python code you're using ?

Answer (score 1):

As [`Series.mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) may return multiple values (in case of multiple values with same count), it always return a `Series`, where the index is a range from 0, that's what you see

To get the first, do

```
mode = df['frequency'].mode()[0]
```

---

Post that could help your understanding

- [Uncomfortable output of mode() in pandas Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42885332/uncomfortable-output-of-mode-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you so much. I had tried to use two index values!